# Some function spaces and their completions.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X=\mathcal{P}[0,1]$ be the set of all polynomials on the interval $[0,1]$, $(q_n)_{n=1}^\infty =\mathcal{Q} \cap [0,1]$. For $P,Q \in X$ consider:

$$d_1(P,Q)=\sup_n \lvert P(q_n)-Q(q_n) \rvert $$ and

$$d_2(P,Q)=\sup_n \lvert P(1/n)-Q(1/n) \rvert. $$

Problems: Are they metric on X? If yes, what are the completions?

What I did so far:

For the metric $d_1$'s triangle inequality, we have

\begin{align}
& \sup_n \lvert P(q_n)- R(q_n) + R(q_n) - Q(q_n) \rvert \\[8pt]
\leq {} & \sup_n \lvert P(q_n)- R(q_n) + R(q_n) - Q(q_n) \rvert \\[8pt]
\leq {} & \sup_n \lvert P(q_n)- R(q_n)\rvert + \sup_n \lvert R(q_n) - Q(q_n) \rvert
\end{align}

My first question is: Can I directly say that the last inequality is true or am I assuming something implicitly that I do not realize?

If these are true,then $d_1$ is a metric. My second question: Is this a valid argument for the second metric also. If not, what changes?

Lastly, about their completions, completion of the $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ is $[0,1]$ in $\mathbb{R}$, and the completion of $X$ in the usual continuous function space with the $\sup$ metric is the whole space. Therefore, my intuition says that the completion should still be the same in terms of the metric $d_1$. But, I do not know whether this is true or not, and if it is true I do not know how to express it mathematically. I do not have anything about the $d_2$ metric, what is the difference with $d_1$? Can you also help with these?

Answer (score 1):

Hints. As far as triangle inequality is concerned you are just using the fact that $\sup(a_n+b_n) \leq \sup a_n+\sup b_n$ so your arguments are correct.

By continuity $d_1$ coincides with the usual sup metric and hence (by Weiersatrss Theorem)  the completion is the space $C[0,1]$ with the sup norm.

The completion under $d_2$ consists of all functions $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ such that $f(\frac 1 n)$ converges as $n \to \infty$. To see that note that for any function that can be approximated in $d_2$ by a polynomial the sequence $f(\frac 1 n)$ is Cauchy, hence convergent. Conversely, given any $f$ with this property and $\epsilon>0$ we can find $N$ such that $|f(\frac 1 n) | <\epsilon$ for $n >N$; there exists a continuous function  $g$ such that $g(\frac  1k)=f(\frac 1 k)$ for $1\leq k \leq N$ and $g=0$ on $[0\frac 1 {N+1}]$. We can approximate this $g$ by a polynomial uniformly. This proves that $f$ is in the completion.